# Data family instance binding illegally to built in syntax: ()

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, type-families

I'm trying to define a [data type family](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families), one of whose parameters results in the type of the empty tuple `()`, but it doesn't compile. Here is a minimal working example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

data family F a
data instance F Int = ()
```

The compiler error thrown says "Illegal binding of built-in syntax: `()`". Why am I getting this error, even though I'm not trying to change the definition of `()`, but rather set it as the output of some computation (evaluation of a type family)?

For what it's worth, the program compiled when `()` is changed to `Bool` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With data families, you're supposed to provide an ADT or GADT definition on the right side of the equation. `()` is not a valid definition of a constructor. `data instance F Int = Bool` declares a single constructor with the name `Bool`, which works, but doesn't have anything to do with the type `Bool`. It's just that `Bool` is available as a constructor name.

What you're trying to do can be realized with type families instead:

```
type family F a
type instance F Int = ()

-- or in closed form
type family F a where
    F Int = ()
```

Or you can give a right hand side for the data instance which's equivalent to `()`:

```
data instance F Int = FUnit
```